# PHP Output Buffering with included files

Tags: php, buffer, output-buffering

I have one file will include other files depending on some conditions, One of these files needs to use output buffering so that the response can be returned to the browser and then some slow actions performed after.

If I run the file that I want to use output buffering directly it works correctly, but If I include this file in another it doesn't work.

For example:

the file that includes: (doesn't work)

```
if($action == 'blah'){
    require_once 'blah.php';       
}
```

blah.php: (works if called directly)

```
ob_start();
$buffer = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();

header('Location: http://www.google.com');

ignore_user_abort(true);
ob_end_flush();

flush();

//Do slow stuff
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: How does it fail? Is there are an error message or something?

Comment: I tried it on built-in PHP server (PHP 5.4.4) and it works well...

Comment: You can enable all error+warning messages via the [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) function, or publish the content of that parent .php file, if it is possible.

Comment: Ahh I think I have sorted it, I was sending some headers in the first file, thank!

Comment: So it's good news and this question can be discarded :)

Comment: Although now I am getting an issue when trying to set content type header inside the ob_clean and ob_end_flush()